# MySQL - How to grant access to only one of n slaves?

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I have one master and two slaves.

Is it possible to restrict a particular read-only user to query only against the second slave (disallowing him from running any queries on the master and the first slave)?

I see that one can do the following to make un-replicated changes to the master, but what I think I need is to make changes to one slave and not the other.

```
SET sql_log_bin = {OFF|ON}
```

And the GRANT syntax allows one to limit what host users come from, but -- as far as I understand -- not which DB server(s) the person can use.

I didn't find much in a web search -- perhaps that's a hint that there's a better way to solve this problem. Basically I'm asking if this can be enforced by the database since the restriction I want applies to just this one user.

Comment: By "hit", do you mean that the user can only access slave 2 (and/or the master)? Or that changes done by that user to the master are only replicated to slave 2? Or do you want to add a user (on the master), but only distribute this specific change (teh queries to add the user) to slave 2 (which would be equivalent to the first option)? Or do you have some kind of load balancer/cluster/... and want the user to automatically be directed to slave 2 only when he connects?

Comment: Edited the question to be less ambiguous. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For context: a slave is basically just a server that copies every action that happened on the master.  Depending on your [configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-formats.html), the slaves will either just run the same queries that have been executed on the master, or apply a list of changes to individual rows to the slave.

To add a user just for a specific slave, you can do this *directly on the slave*. Anything you do here will only affect this slave. If your user currently exists on the master (and slaves), you would first have to drop him/remove his permissions, wait until this change has been replicated to all the slaves (which might also [depend on your configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12086049)), then add/modify this user directly on the slave.

You may need to temporarily disable a [read_only](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only) or [super_read_only](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_super_read_only) setting (on the slave), which exists to prevent accidently executing something on the slave - but that is what you want to do.

Since your slave now deviates (slightly) from the master, if you would now run a query that alters that user on your master (e.g. drop it again), it might have a different effect on the master and the slave. This will depend on your configuration, but keep it in mind.

Comment: Occasionally a slave will go bad and need to be re-seeded. Is it true that one would have to remember to re-do the grant on the special slave after such an event?

Comment: This will depend on your configuration and how you reseed. If you include the "mysql" database, you need to redo (all) your configuration deviations, if not, then not. You can of course use all kinds of methods to remind you, or even to do this (semi-)automatically, e.g. you could add an event (on master, replicated to slaves) that checks `@@hostname` if it's slave 2 server, checks if the user exists, then adds it (on slave 2). Or do it in a cron job that connects to slave 2. But the general idea stays the same: the code to add this user has to be executed only on slave 2.